# how to modify a list that is a value in a dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

If I have a dictionary like so:

```
d = {'USA' : [0,0,0], 'CAN' : [0,0,0]}
```

How can I update a specific element in the value?

My goal is to update it to look like (for example) this:

```
d = {'USA' : [0,1,0], 'CAN' : [1,0,0]}
```

I was thinking something like

```
d['USA'] = d.get('USA')[1] +  1

d['CAN'] = d.get('CAN')[0] +  1
```

but this doesn't seem to work.
Any suggestions?
I hope this is clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have lists inside of your dictionary, so the `d[key]` part of the expression returns a list. Just keep adding `[..]` indexings:

```
d['USA'][1] += 1
d['CAN'][0] += 1
```

You could break it down with intermediary variables if that is easier:

```
sublist = d['USA']
sublist[1] += 1
sublist = d['CAN']
sublist[0] += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be to just say

d['USA'][1] += 1

That will get you the updated list.

Comment: wow ok, thanks! This was much easier than I was making it out to be.

Comment: Just so you see what is happening, we look up the key USA in the dict 'd', and that is a list, we then increment the value at index 1 by 1. I wish you luck on your learning python!

Answer (score 0):

Do

```
d['USA'][1]=d['USA'][1]+1
d['CAN'][0]=d['USA'][0]+1
```

In your example you were replacing the whole list with a single number.